# Regular expression for strings containing a's in multiples of 3

Tags: regex, automata-theory

Can someone please tell me how to generate a regular expression for strings in which number of a's is a multiple of 3? The alphabet set is {a,b}.

I tried to construct a DFA for it first and then derive a RE from that. What I got was ((ba*)(ba*)(ba*))*.

Comment: This RE would match all strings in which the number of a's is a multiple of 3, as well as all other strings. To match only those strings in which the number of a's is a multiple of 3,  could use the following RE: (ba*)(ba*)(ba*)(((ba*)(ba*)(ba*))*)

Comment: Have you swapped a and b? Assuming I understand the notation, shouldn't it be `b*((ab*)(ab*)(ab*))*` or `((b*a)(b*a)(b*a))*b*` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would write the pattern as:

```
^b*(?:(?:ab*){3})*$
```

This matches:

- `^` from the start of the string
- `b*` optional leading `b` zero or more times
- `(?:`

  - `(?:ab*){3}` match `a` followed by zero or more `b` 3 times
- `)*` match this group zero or more times
- `$` end of the string

### Demo